# How to create Hibernate Mapping for a self referencing table

Tags: hibernate, self-referencing-table

I was asked how I would create a hibernate mapping for a column in a table that refers to the primary key of the table.

For example, an Employee table has EMP_ID as primary key and it also has MGR_ID column to know the manager of the employee. As a manager is also an Employee, it would be in the same table. Hence every Employee row has a manager Id which is also an employee.

1. How do we create Hibernate Mapping for this Employee Class?
2. How would the Employee class look like? Does it have just a manager Id in it or it will contain another Employee Object as a member variable.

Kindly help me with this kind of scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

You can have a reference to the `manager` in your `Employee` class.

The entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
     
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long employeeId;
     
    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
     
    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
     
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="manager_id")
    private Employee manager;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="manager")
    private Set<Employee> subordinates = new HashSet<>();
 
    public Employee() {
    }
 
    public Employee(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
         
    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Refer to this link for complete example:

[Hibernate Self Join Annotations One To Many mapping example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/)

Comment: is this approach effective? Suppose, You have Director, Director have manager, manager have employee. So when you open an employee, you will get a manager, inside that manager you will get employee as a child. So it will create a circular data load issue. What is the solution for that?

Comment: this kind of sucks .. you need to introduce a second column just to be able to not have hibernate blow up

Comment: @SayedUzZaman the solution is to add   fetch = FetchType.LAZY in the annotations parameters